# XBrowser app: where are bookmarks stored?

Tags: browser, bookmarks

I have been using this browser for a while now and I am somewhat impressed. I've added some bookmarks which I'd like to import to the browsers on my laptop.
So where do I find them? Or are they in the app itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XBrowser, go to Settings → User Center → Export bookmark to HTML file. The bookmarks would be saved inside /storage/emulated/0/xbrowser/recovery (just use a file manager and visit xbrowser directory in the default storage view). You should be able to use it to import it in a compatible browser.

The bookmarks are actually saved inside a database named mbrowser located inside /data/data/com.xbrowser.xplay/databases/. The table name is bookmark. You would need root access to access the data directory.

Comment: Thanks, I seriously doubted they were wrapped into the app. Old Classic Mac user here; Apple didn't, M$ did but changed, and I've never heard of it happening in a Linux.